# Is it possible to create an indexed view with SQL Server 2008 which selects from another indexed view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, indexed-view

Is it possible to create an indexed view with SQL Server 2008 which selects from another indexed view?

```
create view V1 as (select 1 as abc)
create view V2 as (select abc from V1 group by abc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is "no, it is not possible".

From Microsoft TechNet Site, in an article about performance:

**Q**. I have a view defined on top of another view. SQL Server won't let me index the top-level view. What can I do?

**A**. Consider expanding the definition of the nested view by hand into the top-level view, and then indexing it, indexing the innermost view, or not indexing the view.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) for indexed views (they are plentiful):

- The view must reference only base tables in the same database, not other views.